# Will this InputStream be closed properly if an IOException occurs?

Tags: java, ioexception

I'm trying to properly handle an `IOException` without having to resort to a tonne of nested try/catch statements. 
From reading online I've gathered that this might be the correct way to handle it. but I'm not 100% sure. Is this right?

```
    try (InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream()) { 
            while (in.read(bytesRead) != -1) {
                byteStream.write(bytesRead);
            }   
    }catch(IOException e){
        logger.error("An IOException occurred while streaming a blob from the database", e);
    }
```

Comment: As [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) says, *The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.*

Comment: Thanks, but I just realized, with the above statement, that means that the `ByteArrayOutputStream` needs to be declared within the brackets of the try block too, right?

Comment: OK yeah thanks for that. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InputStream` `in` will be closed, `byteStream` not.